# Translation Holonomy

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, holonomy, cartan-geometry

I'm trying to get a mental image of translation holonomy.

I start with rotational holonomy, which corresponds to intrinsic curvature. This is the quantitative failure of a continuous process of infinitesimal parallel transports using Levi-Civita connection along a closed curved, to return to the same orientation, as the length of the curve tends to 0.

Now, translation holonomy is said to be the quantitative failure of closing the curve, as the length tends to 0, And is the measure of torsion.

So, in the presence of torsion, using the Levi-Civita connection to parallel transport will land in a "wrong" tangent space. So can translation holonomy, torsion at a point, be calculated by using the Levi-Civita connection as in the rotational process, but measuring the vector of displacement from the initial point of the curve after finishing what was meant to be a closed curve, as the length of the curve tends to 0?

Comment: The Levi-Civita connection (on a Riemannian manifold) is by definition torsion-free.

Comment: @TedShifrin So the connection to be used is the combination of spin connection and levi-civita?

Comment: This is for the case of a general affine connection (with torsion) on the tangent bundle.

Comment: @TedShifrin apologies for not mentioning what you mentioned :). Question: With your corrections, my description in words is accurate? Is it way off?

Comment: Well, you need to divide by area bounded by the curve (as is the case with curvature, too). You might check out [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20493/what-is-torsion-in-differential-geometry-intuitively).

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you